# Refresh only the current row of an Aviarc dataset?

Tags: ajax, dataset, aviarc

TLDR: Is it possible to refresh a single dataset row? After an ajax workflow runs I want to refresh the current row from the database, but not the whole dataset (as it can be very large and slow to run the whole query).

---

I have a screen with a record-table that displays a potentially very large dataset, and a button which runs a validation routine against the current row of the dataset. Originally I was running the validation workflow via a screen action, but this means the whole screen would reload when the validation completed, refreshing the entire dataset when only one row has changed.

The problem is I don't have easy access to the dataset that commits the changes to the database; it is a different dataset than what is submitted by the ajax call, and thus the changes aren't automatically sent back to the screen when the ajax request is completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually what I would do is manually copy the changes from the single row edit dataset back to the list dataset during the commit workflow and avoid running a separate query to the database to get the updated row at a later stage.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the row edit dataset. However what I did end up doing was running a temp query on a scratch dataset for just the row that changed, then copying it across like you said.

Comment: I think a short example would be beneficial, edited to add one. Accept if you think so.

Comment: @AdamSharp: you should post a new answer rather than edit other answers to significantly change them.

Comment: @ChrisSpolton Fair enough, though my thought was to improve the answer, as that's basically what solved the problem. Seemed like duplication.

Comment: Similar to this case: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135874/edit-correcting-wrong-information-in-original-answer-and-adding-example-code-has - you've modified the original answer significantly enough to warrant a new answer :-)

Comment: @ChrisSpolton No problem, I'll go ahead and post a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

As I don't have access to the dataset where the row was edited, I needed to retrieve the edited row from the database first, then copy the row back into the actual dataset that's displayed on the screen. For example:

```
<!-- retrieve just the edited row -->
<dataset name="temp-foo" databroker="bar" query="get-bar-by-id">
  <param name="id" value="{$foo.id}" />
</dataset>

<!-- copy the result back to the original dataset -->
<copy-row from-dataset="temp-foo" to-dataset="foo" />
```

Currently there isn't a `<refresh-dataset>` equivalent for just a single row, so you need to use a scratch dataset (or the edited dataset) and copy the result back into the original.